# card.io cordova app integration ios and android

Tags: cordova, ios9, card.io

Am integrating card.io with Cordova app (ionic / ios/ android).

It works well on device - just as it should. On all versions except for iOS 9.1.

On ios9.1, after the scan screen (whether I scan or I choose manual entry), clicking on Done takes me to the app landing page!  How do I fix this?